# injecting php variables into lessphp 0.3.8

Tags: variables, lessphp

I am trying to inject some php variables into my less css using the method described in the lessphp docs. I can do:

```
$lc = new lessc;
$lc->setVariables(array("stylesheetURI" => "foo/bar"));
```

Which ultimately allows me to do:

```
background-image: url("@{stylesheetURI}/img/logo.jpg");
```

Which results in:

```
background-image: url("foo/bar/img/logo.jpg");
```

Thats all perfect & works like a charm ...

However I'd prefer to add a full URL to my image paths. So I am doing:

```
$lc = new lessc;
$lc->setVariables(array("stylesheetURI" => "http://mydomain.com/foo/bar"));
```

But that results in:

```
background-image: url("http/img/logo.jpg");
```

Which is clearly wrong. Has anyone else seen this issue? I've had a dig around in the lessc.inc.php class but it's a bit of a beast and I haven't managed to locate the problem. I presume its related to the colon - do anyone know how to escape this? I've tried a backslash but that doesn't work.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try

```
$less = new lessc;
$less->setVariables(array(
    'rdir'=> '"/resources/default"'
));
echo $less->compileFile($lessFileName);
```

im less file I have

```
img{
    background-image: url(@{rdir}/img.jpg);
}
```

in output I have:

```
img {
  background-image: url(/resources/default/img.jpg);
}
```

when I try

```
$less->setVariables(array(
    'rdir'=> '"http://example.com/resources/default"'
));
```

I get

```
img {
  background-image: url(http://example.com/resources/default/img.jpg);
}
```

lessphp v0.3.9 
you can try add string variable with quotes '"http://example.com/"'